# System boots only with CD inserted

Tags: boot, grub2, debian

I have a weird problem lately:

My system only boots if either a CD is inserted (any CD, not a specific CD(*)) or if I enter UEFI-BIOS before boot.

Otherwise, `grub2` would start but afterwards the screen stays black.

The last thing I did before this problem occured (at least I think this was the last thing) was adding partitions on `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`, generating a raid-1 out of these two partitions and adding the RAID to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and `/etc/fstab`.

My boot-device however is `/dev/sda` (I have a EFI-partition on `/dev/sda1`)

If that helps: I run Debian Wheezy (but also have some packages from experimental).

How can I locate the error and solve it?

(*) I tried the following CDs:

1. A Debian Wheezy Live DVD (actually a DVD, not a CD) => System booted
2. A Mini CD which came with my WiFi-Router (so to say a driver CD) => System booted
3. Another driver CD that came with my printer ages ago => System booted
4. A music CD (Vive la Fête - République Populaire, but I'm quite convinced that doesn't matter) => System *didn't* boot

It looks like all data CDs work...

[edit]

here's my dmesg file (with inserted CD)
http://pastebin.com/cxvv0Hqe
maybe that helps!?

Comment: What is "any CD"? Even a music CD, only a bootable CD, CDs with data?

Comment: After power on, do you have an option `F12 Boot Menu` (or another F-Key)? Does it boot from that menu?

Comment: @ott-- no, I can press DEL or some F-button (I think it is F12), which both brings me to the first page of UEFI-BIOS, where I can choose the boot order (but I'm not exactly sure, I will have a look when I'm home again).

Comment: added a pastebin of `dmesg`

Comment: @ott-- I just checked - I have no boot menu "outside" of UEFI-BIOS. When my computer starts (the mainboard is an ASUS P8H77-I) I can enter the BIOS with `DEL` and `F2` Is there a logfile I can check for the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "solved"??? the problem.

Well I don't really have a solution, as I couldn't identify the reason for the problem. However, the last 2 boots went well without a CD inserted and without entering the BIOS.

What I did was the following:

1. I installed the package `firmware-realtek` as `dmesg -T -l err,crit,alert,emerg` showed me that the realtek firmware was missing.
2. I updated my system with

   aptitude update
   aptitude upgrade
   aptitude dist-upgrade

Now it *seems* like the problem is gone...